# How to create a RadComboBox that is initially not selecting any items?

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

I have a RadComboBox on a page. How do I initiate it without any items being selected?

The following box contains two items, I have tried to use both `ClearSelection()` and `SelectedIndex = -1`, without any luck.

It still looks like this (having its first item selected).

[image: First item selected]

RadComboBoxTest.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RadComboBoxTest.aspx.cs"
  Inherits="Foo.Bar.RadComboBoxTest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"/>
    <div>
      Items:<br/>
      <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbTest" DataValueField="id" 
          DataTextField="name" runat="server"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

RadComboBoxTest.aspx.cs

```
using System;
{
  namespace Foo.Bar
  {
    public partial class RadComboBoxTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        cmbTest.DataSource = new object[]
        {
          new { id =  23, name = "twentythree"},
          new { id =  24, name = "twentyfour"}
        };

        cmbTest.DataBind();
        cmbTest.ClearSelection();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new object, with the id of 0, and name = empty string (" "), and setting the default value to 0

Note: Comment below with Telerik link explains this much better

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want an empty item.

Comment: You are going to have to add an empty row, that does nothing, it is also what is suggested by Telerik it self http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/how-to/insert-a-default-item-when-databinding-radcombobox

Comment: You can do this in plain html like https://jsfiddle.net/p5xpgckz/ so I expect it to be possible with a telerik:RadComboBox as well.